# Left sticky columns disappear when scrolling horizontally mat-table with too many columns are present

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material, mat-table

When scrolling horizontally mat-table, row does not expand to the end of column, just columns that are present on the screen. Because of that, when horizontal scrolling to the right, when mat-row goes out of screen, left sticky columns also leaves (see black border that are present on bottom of mat-row).

Url example link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddqxvn

Is it possible to expand mat-row to all columns (even does that are out of screen), which will keep sticky columns on the left. I am looking for answer with mat-table as element, and not table with 'mat-table' attribute. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Try using the sticky directives `[sticky]="column === 'name1' || column === 'name2'"
      [stickyEnd]="column === 'name33'"` as per documentation. I couldn't find your problem but it looks like the CSS is casing it.

Comment: @LukeKroon, I already tried that with table element and mat-table directive, and it kinda works. But with mat-table as element it doesn't. Mat-table is using flexbox, and mat-row doesn't extend to cell's that are out of display (you can check that in devTools). So when mat-row exits, so does left columns.